# Не могу поймать callback_data

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Разбираюсь с aiogram 3.x

Не могу поймать ни одного callback*а

```
router = Router()

...

@router.callback_query(F.data == "review")
async def cancel_FSM_and_main_menu(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await callback.message.answer(
        text="Вы хотите оставить отзыв анонимно?",
        reply_markup=yes_no
    )
```

Есть вот такой хэндлер(Роутер зарегистрирован)

```
dp.include_router(review.router)
```

Есть кнопки

```
builder = ReplyKeyboardBuilder()
builder.row(
        types.KeyboardButton(text="Оставить отзыв", callback_data="review")
    )
builder.row(
        types.KeyboardButton(text="Актуальные цены", callback_data="price")
    )
builder.row(
        types.KeyboardButton(text="Поделиться фото и видео", callback_data="upload")
    )
main_menu_key = builder.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True)
 
Структура примерно такая:
Config -> bot_config.py(Подключение роутера) \n
keyboards -> main_menu.py \n
handlers -> review.py \n
```

В логах пишет, что хэндлеров для `callback_data = 'review'` нет

```
INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=XXXXX is not handled. Duration 0 ms by bot id=XXXXXX
```

Куда копать? Убирал роутеры, ничего не менялось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно пишет, что нет.
У `Reply` кнопок нет аргумента `callback_data`, только `text`. ПО сути, нажатие на такую кнопку равносильно простому вводу текста.
Но такой аргумент есть у `Inline` кнопок, которые прикрепляются к сообщению.
В ваших примерах необходимо использовать `message`, а не `callback_query`:

```
router = Router()

...

@router.message(F.data == "review")
async def cancel_FSM_and_main_menu(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(
        text="Вы хотите оставить отзыв анонимно?",
        reply_markup=yes_no
    )
```

Comment: Спасибо, совсем из головы вылетело, хочу всё таки построить на callback*ах, так что, буду менять тип кнопок